# Issues properly sending data as POST request

Tags: php, curl, mailchimp

I'm working with Mailchimp's API and I'm stuck on this step from the [documentation](https://apidocs.mailchimp.com/oauth2/):

```
Step 4: Your application must make an out-of-band request to the access_token_uri using the "code" returned

        - This is a POST request
        - as you can see, grant_type, client_id, client_secret, code, and redirect_uri are *all* POSTed
******************************************************************************************

access_token_uri: https://login.mailchimp.com/oauth2/token

REQUEST:

POST /oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: oauth2-draft-v10
Host: login.mailchimp.com
Accept: application/json
Content-Length: 198
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

grant_type=authorization_code&client_id=635959587059&client_secret=0da3e7744949e1406b7b250051ee1a95&code=1edf2589e664fd317f6a7ff5f97b42f7&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2F192.168.1.8%2Foauth%2Fcomplete.php
```

This is what I've tried but `$dec_respo` keeps coming back as NULL:

```
 $client_id = 'xxxxxxxxxx';
 $client_secret = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'; //client_secret from creating app in MC  (see README)
 $redirect_uri = 'https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fimport%2Fsuccess_mc.html';
 $code_got ='67add42184b8f71a9100f505d3f13744';

$headr = array();
$headr[] = 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded';


$post_data = json_encode(array('grant_type'=>'authorization_code','client_id' => $client_id,'client_secret' => $client_secret, 'code'=> $code_got, 'redirect_uri'=> $redirect_uri));
$url = 'https://login.mailchimp.com/oauth2/token';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headr);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$response = curl_exec( $ch );
$dec_respo = (json_decode($response, true));
var_dump($dec_respo);
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Dont send json, the api is expecting regular post data string.

Comment: Can you give me some idea of what the string should have in it and how I incorporate it into the CURL lines I have?

Comment: replace `json_encode()` with `http_build_query()`

Comment: Still getting `NULL` back

Comment: Is the api actually returning json? `var_dump($response);` what do you get?

Comment: Do you have a link to the documentation?#

Comment: @Steve Here's the link: https://apidocs.mailchimp.com/oauth2/. `var_dump($response)` give me this gibberish: `string(51) "‹ªVJ-*Ê/R²RÊÌ+KÌÉL‰O/JÌ+Qªÿÿ’¸j"`

Comment: Three things: 1. Use Guzzle or PHP Requests rather than raw cURL if you can. 2. You don't need to use http_build_query(), `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` can take an associative array and figure it out. 3. That looks like a gzipped response that you're not decoding. I think `CURLOPT_ENCODING` will sort that out for you. ([CURL_OPT docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)).

Comment: Hi !, you fix this? I'm having the same problem @jonmrich